# I am unsure of the correct syntax to use in eiffel?

Tags: syntax, eiffel

I have a feature

```
feature --compare
is_less alias "<" (other: MONEY): BOOLEAN
        -- Is current money less than `other'?
    local
        temp: BOOLEAN
    do
        temp := cents < other.cents
        Result := temp
    end
```

It just checks two number of cents (cents < other.cents) is greater than.
I cannot get the Result to return true even if i set it too true:

Result := temp -----> Result := true

Comment: `print (create {MONEY}.make (1) < create {MONEY}.make (2))` prints `True` for me. How do you call feature `is_less` from `MONEY`?

Comment: Say i have two MONEY objects m1 and m2. m1.is_less(m2)

Comment: `create m1.make (1); create m2.make (2); print (m1.is_less (m2))` prints `True` for me as well. Is it different for you? Which compiler version do you use? What is the type of `cents`?

Comment: I get false with that statement. I am using 13.11. cents is INTEGER_64

Comment: It still works flawless for me with the version of the compiler you mention. I would suggest you to post complete code of the example with the issue to their [support site](http://support.eiffel.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using 13.11 and it works well for me.

```
is_less alias "<" (other: like Current): BOOLEAN
    require
        not_void: other /= Void
    do
        Result := cents < other.cents
    end
```

In another class I call this function and it works as expected.

```
do_compare
    local
        m1, m2: MONEY
    do
        create m1.make_from_volume (1)
        create m2.make_from_volume (2)
        print(m1.is_less (m2))
    end
```

So I wonder how did not check if the Result is True or not? How did you pass the argument to it?